# Trigger Help - unable to trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, cursor

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TGR_UPT_CGPA
AFTER INSERT ON onlineAssessment
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_totalCredit NUMBER(3):=0;
  v_learnerID VARCHAR(15);
  v_grade onlineAssessment.grade%TYPE;
  v_gradeNum NUMBER(2);

  CURSOR Grade_CURSOR IS
      SELECT COUNT(grade), grade
      FROM onlineAssessment
      WHERE learnerID = :new.learnerID GROUP BY grade;

BEGIN
  SELECT learnerID into v_learnerID
  FROM onlineAssessment
  WHERE AssessmentID = :new.AssessmentID;

  SELECT SUM(C.courseCredits) into v_totalCredit
  FROM Courses C, onlineAssessment A
  WHERE A.learnerID = :new.learnerID AND C.CourseID = A.CourseID;

  OPEN Grade_CURSOR;

  LOOP
    FETCH Grade_CURSOR INTO v_gradeNum, v_grade;
    EXIT WHEN Grade_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
    IF v_grade='A' THEN
      v_totalCredit := v_totalCredit+(v_gradeNum*4);
    ELSIF v_grade='B' THEN
      v_totalCredit := v_totalCredit+(v_gradeNum*3);
    ELSIF v_grade='C' THEN
      v_totalCredit := v_totalCredit+(v_gradeNum*2);
    ELSIF v_grade='D' THEN
      v_totalCredit := v_totalCredit+(v_gradeNum*2);
    ELSE
      v_totalCredit := v_totalCredit+(v_gradeNum*0);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE Grade_CURSOR;

  UPDATE learners
  SET CGPA = v_totalCredit
  WHERE learnerID = :new.learnerID;


END;
/
```

Trigger created with no problem, but when i insert new data into onlineAssessment Table, it will not update the learner's CGPA data..I cannot solve this provle, please help me, thanks..

I try to figure out almost half day, i could not solve this problem. I am new to oracle SQL.

Comment: Hi , when posting please always include the error you're getting, which I assume is a mutating table error? Can you please explain, in English, _exactly_ what you are trying to do?

Comment: What is the error, and on what line?  We are not mind readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger has code in it that will cause a "mutating trigger" error. Google "ora-04091" to see the details (here is one [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora04091.php)). Basically, you cannot query the table whose context is currently being updated in the trigger.  In your case, you have a trigger on onlineAssessment, but in the code, you have this select:

```
 SELECT learnerID into v_learnerID
  FROM onlineAssessment
  WHERE AssessmentID = :new.AssessmentID;
```

You need to remove the select, and simply reference :new.learnerID. You are already referencing that in the next query:

```
 SELECT SUM(C.courseCredits) into v_totalCredit
  FROM Courses C, onlineAssessment A
  WHERE A.learnerID = :new.learnerID AND C.CourseID = A.CourseID;
```

so I am not even sure what the purpose of the 1st select was.  Just remove it, and you should be OK.